# (this) after function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, declaration

Can somebody explain me what `(this)` means at the end of the following code:

```
var a=(function(_this){
 return function() {
  //do something
  return smth;
 };
})(this);
```

What is the sense of such coding?

---

Going forward, what does the following code do, when placed in .js file and invoked by html  tag?

```
(function() {
 Emitter=(function(){
  function Emitter() {}
  ...
  return Emitter;
 })();
 A=(function(_super){...})(Emitter);
}).call(this);
```

how to instantiate object A from outside the js file?

Comment: search for 'Immediately Invoked Function expression'. There are many many many many questions and articles about it. It's a common pattern for many things but you will probably see it mostly on plugins and libraries

Comment: It is a self invoking function. I think when you need to carry around a reference to the object you close the self invoking function like that.

Comment: Did either one of these answers answer your question?  If so, please select one as the "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole structure is a means of saving the current value of `this` so that a function call later on can use it.

That could all be done also with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this which (if you understand what `.bind()` does might be easier to follow):

```
function myFunc(_this) {
    // do something
}

var a = myFunc.bind(null, this);
```

---

Here are the various steps in what happens in the code you've shown:

`this` will have a value from the surrounding context when this code is originally executed (which you don't show).  It is being passed into a self-executing function as an argument often referred to as an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) which is just a function call that happens immediately inline as the code is initially run.

Within that function it is given an argument name of `_this`.

When that function executes, it returns another function.  The body of that inner function also has access to `_this`.

When that inner function is returned, it is assigned to the variable `a`.

The upshot of all this is that one can call `a()` and the internals of that function, when it executes will be able to access `_this` which contains the value of the original `this`.

So, it's essentially a means of creating a function that when executed will have access to the original value of `this` even though the context will have changed when `a()` is later called.  So, its essentially saving the value of `this` for a specific function to use later.

More detail would require more context about what is going on inside that internal function, what the `this` value was in the original context and how `a()` is used later.

---

This is one particular use of an IIFE.  They have many other uses.

Answer (score 2):

This is a self-executing function, which is used to save a reference to "this" through the function's closure. It is used to hold on to the reference to "this" at the function's first execution time.

You can also use Function.prototype.bind() to achieve a similar result of saving a reference to "this":
[MDN - Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)